# Azure Spring Cloud deployment of SpringBoot stuck at deployment step

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, maven, azure-spring-cloud

I have a Spring Boot application configured for deployment to Azure Spring Cloud. I have a build and I am trying to deploy it but every deployment gets stuck and does not finish.

Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-apps-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <subscriptionId>${azure.subscription.id}</subscriptionId>
                    <clusterName>cluster1</clusterName>
                    <appName>${azure.appName}</appName>
                    <deployment>
                        <cpu>1</cpu>
                        <memoryInGB>1</memoryInGB>
                        <instanceCount>1</instanceCount>
                        <runtimeVersion>Java 11</runtimeVersion>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <filtering/>
                                <mergeId/>
                                <targetPath/>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.jar</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </deployment>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Log:

```
$ mvn azure-spring-apps:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< com.test:spring-boot-app >---------------------
[INFO] Building spring-boot-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- azure-spring-apps-maven-plugin:1.11.0:deploy (default-cli) @ spring-boot-app ---
[INFO] Auth type: OAUTH2
[INFO] Retry attempts have been exhausted after 0 attempts.
[INFO] Retry attempts have been exhausted after 0 attempts.
[INFO] Retry attempts have been exhausted after 0 attempts.
[INFO] Retry attempts have been exhausted after 0 attempts.
Username: 2dor
[INFO] Subscription: Azure subscription 
[INFO] Reflections took 152 ms to scan 4 urls, producing 16 keys and 525 values
[INFO] Start updating deployment(default)...
```

I have waited for hours and it does not finish

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `-X` flag to `mvn azure-spring-apps:deploy -X` to get more detailed logs.